# UEFI Mode - File System Not Found

Tags: windows-10, uefi

I've installed a new SSD into a laptop of mine, and I need to install Windows 10 on it.  I have anEUFI firmware (not classic BIOS nor enabled CSM), but it will not recognize the boot media.  Every time I hit "Add Boot Option" I get "File System Not Found".

I have confirmed the boot media is UEFI capable and working - I used it yesterday on another machine successfully in UEFI mode AFTER I saw the issue on this one.  The boot media is on an external USB BluRay player.  I confirmed the firmwareis set to normal UEFI and USB support is enabled.  The BluRay player is visible when an OS is installed, so the USB ports are working.  I have updated the firmware to the latest version.  I have removed the CMOS battery to try and drain/reset the BIOS.  Nothing has changed though - I still cant select a boot device.

Is there some way to reset the UEFI so it can detect the USB media?

Comment: Not all UEFI capable systems support booting from an external optical drive.You could create a bootable usb stick instead by using [Microsoft's Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows-10) or [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: It'll have to be Rufus, considering its a customized image.  Is there an easy setting to check if it can boot to an external optical?  Setting up Rufus will take some time here because of policy reasons.

Comment: No, it completely depends on your UEFI firmware.

Comment: Alright, using Rufus to turn it from a BluRay into an external USB HDD worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will not allow non-OEM installations likely. Try disabling `Secure Boot` and enabling `Legacy Support` in BIOS. This will allow installations from most media devices.

Comment: I specifically need Secure Boot Enabled and Legacy mode disabled.

Comment: Apparently by "non-OEM" they mean an authentic Debian too?